# Asp.net webservice always recieving null values from soap ui

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm posting below message from soap UI and i always receiving null value in webservice. Whatever message I'm posting from soap UI it is taking as null only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<env:Header/>
<env:Body>
Test
</env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Below is my simple WebService

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://test.com/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
public class TestService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

    [WebMethod]
    public int TestMethod(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            File.WriteAllText("D:\\abc.xml", message);
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the wrong SOAP. Are you sure you passed an updated WSDL to soapUI?

Comment: john - Thanks for the reply. What do you mean by wrong SOAP? Iam passing correct WSDL only to soapUI

Comment: I've never seen a WSDL with a message like that. I'm not convinced that you passed the correct WSDL.

Comment: John - As per my above code i just created a webservice which is having one test method. To test that code from soap Ui im sending the messsage as shown like above. Im getting null values in service....what do you mean by correct WSDL? can you please more elaborate.

Comment: I don't believe that the WSDL generated from the service you're showing would cause soapUI to send the message you're showing. I don't believe it's even valid to just have text immediately within the `<soap:Body>` tags.

Comment: you are true..The soap UI is creating like <soap:Body> only. But i modified to <env:Body> because our external vendor is using a tool to send the message to my webservice and they are sending like above message which i posted in the original question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21155/discussion-between-reddy39-and-john-saunders)

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying which method to call or the parameters of that method in your body.  You'll need something like this:

```
<env:Body>
  <m:TestMethod xmlns:m="http://tempuri.org">
    <message>Test</message>
  </m:TestMethod>
</env:Body>
```

Comment: Mike - Thanks for your response. Im still facing the same issue after adding the above thing also